# Meaning of this piece of dialogue in The Call of the Wild?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, colloquialisms, literature, dialogue

Here is an excerpt from Chapter 1 of The Call of the Wild by Jack London:

> Yet his time came, in the end, in the form of a little weazened man
> who spat broken English and many strange and uncouth exclamations
> which Buck could not understand.
>
> "Sacredam!" he cried, when his eyes lit upon Buck. "Dat one dam bully
> dog! Eh? How moch?"
>
> **"Three hundred, and a present at that,"** was the prompt reply of the
> man in the red sweater. **"And seem' it's government money, you ain't
> got no kick coming, eh, Perrault?"**
>
> Perrault grinned. Considering that the price of dogs had been boomed
> skyward by the unwonted demand, it was not an unfair sum for so fine
> an animal. The Canadian Government would be no loser, nor would its
> despatches travel the slower. Perrault knew dogs, and when he looked
> at Buck he knew that he was one in a thousand—"One in ten t'ousand,"
> he commented mentally.

What does "present" mean in this context?

Also, what exactly does the second part in the bold mean in simpler English?

Comment: A present=a gift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ... and a present at that:

It's worth much more than 300, so it's like a gift.

2. ... ain't got no kick coming:

Since it's the government's money, you have no reason to complain.